# Generating nested routes in a custom generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-generation, routes, generator

I'm building a generator in rails that generates a frontend and admin controller then adds the routes to the routes file. I can get the frontend working with this:

```
m.route_resources controller_file_name
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same for the nested admin route (admin/controller_file_name). Anyone know how to generate these routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code for `route_resources`, it doesn't look like it will do anything beyond a bog-standard `map.resources :foos`.

Instead, let's write our own method to deal with this issue, based on the original

```
def route_namespaced_resources(namespace, *resources)
  resource_list = resources.map { |r| r.to_sym.inspect }.join(', ')
  sentinel = 'ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|'
  logger.route "#{namespace}.resources #{resource_list}"
  unless options[:pretend]
    gsub_file 'config/routes.rb', /(#{Regexp.escape(sentinel)})/mi do |match|
      "#{match}\n  map.namespace(:#{namespace}) do |#{namespace}|\n     #{namespace}.resources #{resource_list}\n  end\n"
    end
  end
end
```

We can start this off as a local method in your generator, which you can now call with:

```
m.route_namespaced_resources :admin, controller_file_name
```